Visual prolog (ver.7.5) variable is not completely bound
So I have this part of my code:
   append_list([], List2, List2).
append_list([Head|Tail], List2, [Head|TailResult]):-
   append_list(Tail, List2, TailResult).

And I get this error no matter what I change in code:
e609 Variable 'Head' is not completely bound
I use "append_list" in following cases:
append_list(_, Middle, ABTrainStations),
 append_list([station(AName, _), station(BName, BTime)], _, Middle). 


So I am looking for some help, because I've no experience in Visual Prolog whatsoever.
I've tried to ask some of the code related AI's but it was all in vain.
